# Standard versus Enhanced Owner's Title Insurance

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, title-insurance

We are getting ready to close on our house, and I was wondering the circumstances under which an enhanced title insurance is better than a standard ALTA owner's title insurance. Here is a comparison chart.
http://www.kvslawgroup.com/calculate_costs/title_insurance

Specifically, I am seeking practical examples of issues with the title where the enhanced policy would offer better coverage than the standard.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it listed on the site you referred to? Quite clearly, too... What's the question really?